# Handle exception java : retry a loop after n exceptions

Tags: java, loops, exception

in example below :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //...
    
    products.foreach( product -> { 
        //...
        
        try{
              int n=10/Random().nextInt(2);
              System.out.println(n);
              
        }catch(Exception e){
              
              System.out.println(e);
        }
          
      //...
      
    })  
}
```

I want to retry the loop from the beginning if there is an exception, maximum ***three*** exceptions.

So Is there a way to do that easily ?

here I used Random().nextInt(2)  to illustrate my situation; so if it is equal to 0, it is going to throw an exception

Comment: at the end of `try` add `x = 6;`

Comment: I'm sure about the programming language, products is a stream variable, sorry I didn't mention that